# Logical Replication from a AWS RDS Postgres Read Replica

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, replication, logical-replication

Basicaly we have a primary Postgres Database A in the AWS RDS and we also have a replica of it, let's call it B. There is a replication process from A ---> B on AWS side itself. And I have another database Instance, let's call it C. I am trying to enable logical replication from B ---> C. As a one step, I change the parameter of database B **rds.logical_replication = 1** and restart the Postgres Service.

As a next step, I check from the server side the parameters with this query :

```
SELECT name,setting 
FROM pg_settings 
WHERE name IN ('wal_level','rds.logical_replication');
```

But these parameters are still same: **rds.logical_replication = off** and **wal_level=replica**. What should be the steps to enable logical replication from AWS Read Replica instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which engine version are you using?
According to the AWS documentation it's only possible from 14.1 onwards.

> You can't create a read replica from another read replica if your RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance is running a PostgreSQL version earlier than 14.1. RDS for PostgreSQL supports cascading read replicas on RDS for PostgreSQL version 14.1 and higher releases only. For more information, see Using cascading read replicas with RDS for PostgreSQL.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.html#USER_PostgreSQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.Limitations

Comment: it is on 11.16. But I am not try to create another read replica from the read replica. I am just try to use read replica as a publisher for my other database instance.

Comment: From my understanding you can't enable logical replication in read replicas only primary instance. For instance AWS DMS CDC replication which relies on logical replication, explicitly states that it don't support read replicas. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html

Comment: PostgreSQL 16 enabled logical replication from physical replication standbys. https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/logical-replication-on-standbys-in-postgres-16